# U2 Toolkit for .Net Provider 2.2.2 Not Displaying in ADO.NET Connection Manager

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, u2netdk, rocket-u2

I've been trying to install the U2 Toolkit for .Net Provider 2.2.2 and wanting to utilise SSIS with it.

Initially I installed Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT 2017 but I was unable to view the U2 .Net Provider option when creating a new ADO.net connection. So I then installed SSDT 2015 thinking it may be a compatibility issue and was still unable to view the U2 .Net Provider option.

[Visual Studio 2015 ADO.Net Connection Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOyxH.png)

When I start a Windows Form project, I am able to add the U2 Connectors to the project but unable to see it in an SSIS project as above.

I've gone through the documentation for the U2 Provider and it says it is compatible with Visual studio 2015 & 2017, and SSIS & SSRS is compatible as well. I've also registered the Provider using the configuration tool that was included with the U2 Provider. Registering the U2 Provider modifies the ProviderDescriptors.xml file but it doesn't look like it does anything?

What could I be doing wrong? Is there a step in registering a ADO.Net provider that I'm missing?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've figured out the reason. The installer didn't register the assemblies in the GAC and did not include the provider in machine.config on two machines I've tested for some reason.

Once I've registered the assemblies in the GAC and made sure the items in machine.config matched the entries in the GAC, it worked. Not 100% sure why but I'm guessing it's just how Windows and the .Net Framework works.